# good commercial memory debugging tools for C on Linux

Tags: memory-management

I have tried using electric fence to debug large C application on linux. It runs as a daemon and probably because of it (or some other issue that I cannot troubleshoot) electric fence is not working. Is there a good commerical tool that will help me debug memory issues?

Comment: valgrind also is not of mch use since it shows a memory leak because we preallocate a large chunk of memory. I am specifically looking for memory overrun issues

Comment: What do you mean, 'Not of much use'? Valgrind does the job of finding overflows pretty well, just ignore memory leak warnings or find some options to remove them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you look at the [intel tools for linux](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/linux-tool-suites/) as it contains a debugger and vtune which are all very good indeed.  These will work on AMD tools but clearly do not have a in-depth knowledge of the chip set.

Comment: thanks. This was good and gave me a clue. We are on AMD. I checked AMD site but did not find anything substantial. Thank you again. I think I should specify that it is best to get a processor agnostic tools because the hardware specs change from time to time.